# Failed prop type: Invalid prop `iconBack` of type `object` supplied to `Component`, expected `number` in test file

Tags: unit-testing, react-native, jestjs

I test a component contains a child component has Image. I define propTypes of Image in in child component is `number`. At main components I passed the image props by `import`. But test file run warning **Invalid prop `iconBack` of type `object` supplied to `HeaderVideoNavigation`**

[image]

This is code at `HeaderVideoNavigation`

```
const HeaderVideoNavigation = props => (
  <Container>
    <IconContent>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={props.onPressBackIcon}>
        <IconButton isDisplay source={props.iconBack} />
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </IconContent>
    {!!props.editText && <EditText>{props.editText}</EditText>}
  </Container>
)
```

and at main Component

```
<Header>
  <HeaderVideoNavigation
    onPressBackIcon={closeModal}
    iconBack={Images.iconBackWhite}
  />
</Header>
```

Comment: hi @Hoai di you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The warning basically says that iconBackWhite is an object rather than a number which is expected in IconButton component of its source prop.

```
<IconButton isDisplay source={props.iconBack} />
```